# No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement php

Tags: php, database, sql-insert

Help, I have created a method in a connection class that connect to the local database to insert a record. I have allowed parameters to be allowed to be passed into the method to dynamically choose the table, columns and values.

In this method I implode the columns and placeholders to the query which is fine. The problem I have is binding the values to the placeholders. I keep getting an error stating 'No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement'. I have searched some of the same questions on here but none seem to solve my problem. Thanks

```
public function InsertQuery( $table, $values, $cols)
{
    $placeholders = array(); 

    foreach ($values as $val) {
        $placeholders[] = '?';      
    }

    $placeholderList = implode(',', $placeholders);
    $query = "INSERT INTO $table".'('.implode(',',$cols).') VALUES '. '('.$placeholderList.')';
    $connect = $this->dbConnection;

    if ($stmt = $connect->prepare($query)) {
        $param_type = array("ssis"); 
        $params_array = array_merge($param_type,$values);
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params_array);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$param_type` suggests, that you already know how many columns you're going to have (4), but you're function appears to be "variable".If you're function doesn't get exactly 4 values, it will fail, because `ssis` is for exactly 4 params.

Solution would likely be, that you look into your columns and just remember, when the integer field comes and build your `$param_type` string accordingly. Or if there is any combination of types of values allowed, well, you get the picture ... I hope.